# .NetCore Web Apis Slow response Time with EFCore

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

EfCore's DbContext is taking too much time to get initialized when only a small amount of users are using my web app, how can it be fixed?

I have developed a .net core 2.0 web api that uses EFCore with a dynamic repository pattern.

The initialization of db context is done through dependency injection  (scoped lifetime)

Speed Issue :

- When 1 user is using the app, the response time of APIs are normal
- In opposite when there is only 40 users using my web api simultaneously, my api starts to get really slow until it reaches sometimes 40 secs and more each.

After doing some investigations using AppInsights, i have noticed that when the dependency calls duration is high => the request duration is high too.

In addition i noticed that the initialisation of dbcontext is taking too much time (greater than 5 secs) even though it's only 40 users who are using my web app simultaneously

Does anyone know what could be the reason of this slowness?

N.B : i am using no tracking and i did a lot of optimization but it is still too slow

```
services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(
               options =>
               {
                   options
                   .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                   .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)); 
               }, 
               ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Sql database side :
[Database Computing Utitlization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FukuH.png)

Live Metric:
[Live Metric Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh7GD.png)

I expect that the web app respond with the same response time wether there is 1 user using it or hundreds

Comment: There's no way to know without seeing your app. There's nothing inherent in EF Core that would cause slowness like this. However, as with all throughput, it depends on both the resources of your web server and the resources of your database server. As well as the network between the two. (Are they in the same subnet, same region, etc.) You might also want to try using `AddDbContextPool` instead, as you might be exhausting your available connections.

Comment: Are you getting a contention in your SQL Server as SQL Server executes queries on one object in a sequence? If you are fetching data, make sure that your columns are properly indexed. According to my experience, 95% of the time it is SQL who is the culprit in these scenarios.

Comment: I tried to use the AppDbContextPool instead but it is still the same speed issue and regarding sql server how to check if its executing queries in a sequence?
I have noticed as well that the Compute utilization on the sql database is really high